# How to Reset Oracle Sequence Safely?

Tags: oracle, sequence

I want to reset my Oracle Sequence to 0 everyday my code like this:

```
create or replace procedure reset_seq(p_seq_name in varchar2) is
  l_val number;
begin
  execute immediate 'select ' || p_seq_name || '.nextval from dual'
    INTO l_val;   --1

  execute immediate 'alter sequence ' || p_seq_name || ' increment by -' ||
                    l_val || ' minvalue 0'; --2
  execute immediate 'select ' || p_seq_name || '.nextval from dual'
    INTO l_val;  --3

  execute immediate 'alter sequence ' || p_seq_name ||
                    ' increment by 1 minvalue 0';  --4

end;
```

but after run about 2 years later , suddenly I get an error, the increment is an negative int like -16 and  the start value also is -16. So anyone can help me to explain this issue.

What I think is that.

1. the procedure run to step 3 ,after that the current increment is -16 and nextval is 0.
2. other client request the sequence ,but the current increment is -16 so the next value is -16
3. the exception occured when the procedure run to step 4.

but I’m not sure about this, can anyone explain it to me. Thanks.

Comment: Your interpretation seems reasonable, but what was the actual error you got - and did any other sessions see any errors? Do you have logs from whatever else might have tried to access the sequence between steps 3 and 4, both to confirm that actually happened, and to see if they had errors?  (Also where are you seeing that "the start value also is -16"?)

Comment: the error is ORA-08004, my C# program error shows like this 'IVR_ORDER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL goes below MINVALUE Cannot instantiate'

Comment: Your C# program that executes the procedure you showed, or something else that accesses the sequence? Either way, that does support your analysis, that essentially you're getting two `nextval` calls between steps 2 and 4. (This may not be the first time that has happened; it just may be the first time another session has called it between steps 2 and 3, causing the procedure to error. If the other session calls it between steps 3 and 4 then your procedure won't error - that session will get the ORA-08004 instead. You might not have noticed that.)

Comment: Thank you @Alex Poople The Oracle procedure reset the sequence.The Oracle job use the procedure to reset the sequence. my c# program accesses the  sequence nextval at any time.         So how can I aovid this error.

Comment: I don't think you can do anything from the procedure side, or with locks etc. - as the `alter` DDL will implicitly commit and free any locks being held. I think you would have to make your program handle it - make sure it doesn't try to access the sequence at the same time. I only have vague ideas - check if the job is running; or use a table to record your own lock; but those have timing issues too. Check the job ran today. Or have your program catch the ORA-08004 (or getting zero for nextval) and try again maybe. (And if doing that, have the proc ignore that error too, at least on step 3).

Comment: The sequence is like this when error happens                                                             
![img](http://t2.qpic.cn/mblogpic/746ea60b3a41dca83fac/460)  It looks like the sequence is incorrect so my program will always have an error when get the sequence next value.my idea is to keep the procedure atomicity. but I can't find any way to solve it.

Comment: If step 3 catches and ignores the ORA-08004 it will still do step 4 and 'fix' the broken sequence. But you're still left with your program that made the nextval call between steps 2 and 3, which will have got zero (which step 3 expected) as a result - so should probably call nextval again to get 1 if it sees that; or if *that* gets the ORA-08004. (Or both, if it could make two calls between steps 2 and 4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that both your job-submitted procedure and your external program could both call `nextval` between steps 2 and 4; and could call in either order; and potentially the external program could make multiple calls.

You could try to mitigate that by changing both the procedure and the external call.

At the moment if step 3 errors the procedure terminates and step 4 is never reached, so all future calls to `nextval` will continue to error. So you could trap and ignore the ORA-08004 error, on the basis that you'll only get that if there has been an external call between steps 2 and 3, the sequence has therefore been incremented back to zero by that call and thus step 3 is effectively redundant in that scenario:

```
create or replace procedure reset_seq(p_seq_name in varchar2) is
  l_val number;
  e_8004 exception;
  pragma exception_init(e_8004, -8004);
begin
  execute immediate 'select ' || p_seq_name || '.nextval from dual'
    INTO l_val;   --1

  execute immediate 'alter sequence ' || p_seq_name || ' increment by -' ||
                    l_val || ' minvalue 0'; --2

  begin
    execute immediate 'select ' || p_seq_name || '.nextval from dual'
      INTO l_val;  --3
  exception
    when e_8004 then
      -- nextval has already been called by someone else
      null;
  end;

  execute immediate 'alter sequence ' || p_seq_name ||
                    ' increment by 1 minvalue 0';  --4

end;
```

Now if an external program calls `nextval` between steps 2 and 3 then you'll get the error at step 3 but ignore it, and step 4 will still happen.

Your external program will get a `nextval` value of zero if it makes its call between steps 2 and 3; and will get the ORA-08004 if it calls between steps 3 and 4 - or if it makes multiple calls in the window between steps 2 and 4. So, assuming you don't expect zero to be a valid result (which seems reasonable as you wouldn't normally ever get that), you can make repeated calls until you get a non-zero answer and no error. In pseudocode something like:

```
loop
  val = seq.nextval;
  if error == -8004 then continue;
  if val == 0 then continue;
  break;
end loop
```

You could consider putting that logic into a PL/SQL function and have your program call the function instead of accessing the sequence directly, both to hide that complexity and to avoid having to repeat it if you have more than one program potentially affected.